# Application Spyder error during installation

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I want to install Spyder 5.1.5 on Windows 10 but I get this error. Is there way around it? I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda but the same error persists.

I also tried the following on the Anaconda prompt but to no avail.

```
conda remove spyder-kernels
conda install spyder-kernels=0.*
```

[image]

Comment: With the level of details you give about the error and your setup I do not think we can help here...

Comment: @SherlockBourne I have now added more details.

Comment: Can you try to launch spyder from the anaconda command prompt and then post the full error output that you get?